# Stored procedure not returning anything when used to select from table containing data in different languages

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a functionality wherein the user types something in a textbox and at the back end a stored procedure is used with dynamic query for searching from a table which supports both English and Arabic languages.

It works fine with English words, but when I search with Arabic words it returns nothing. My stored procedure looks like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SimilarItems_Search] 
  @Search           NVARCHAR(1000) = NULL
, @Culture          NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SET     @Query =  'SELECT   *
                        FROM  Products
                        WHERE [Status] = 1
                        AND CultureID = dbo.udf_GetCurrentCultureID('''+@Culture+''')  '    

    IF(ISNULL(@Search,'') <> '')

            SET     @Query = @Query +       
                        '  AND 
                        (
                            ProductName  like ''%'+@Search+'%'' 
                            OR ProductTitle like ''%'+@Search+'%''
                            OR Author like ''%'+@Search+'%''
                            OR Publication like ''%'+@Search+'%''
                        ) '
EXEC (@Query)
END
```

I know for nvarchar values you have to prefix it with N. I have tried in  the sql editor and it works fine, but how to do it from my C# method. I have also used

```
set @Search = N''+@Search+''
```

but it is printing '??????????'

Comment: Shouldn't you execute @Query somewhere?

Comment: Could the ????? be because the output is being displayed in a control that does not support Arabic characters?

Comment: Sorry about the execute I got that edited.

Comment: Actually ??????? the result I am getting in sql only while checking. The thing is when I execute this statement : Exec [dbo].[usp_SimilarItems_Search] 'اختبار كتاب اللغة العربية','ar-kw', I get ???, but with this statement Exec [dbo].[usp_SimilarItems_Search] 0,0,0,0,'SEARCH',N'اختبار كتاب اللغة العربية','ar-kw', it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

To find out exact problem, try printing raw output on the page and also see what exactly is query returning in debug mode!

Seems like your control doesn't support language or your browser / windows needs installation of appropriate fonts, that should do.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. My point is how to prefix the N when I am calling the procedure.

Comment: Did you try adding N'' in where condition? For e.g ProductName  like N''%'+@Search+'%''

Answer (score 0):

If the question is understood properly then the answer can be found here

[Select Query giving output as ??????????? with different language text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097213/select-query-giving-output-as-with-different-language-text/30097253#30097253)

The catch is the moment I assigned an nvarchar variable with that Arabic text without the 'N' prefix it lost its Unicode property, so after that how much I try it cannot be changed. So the main idea is when you have such type of scenario better prefix it from the application side itself, when you are passing the parameters. In this way the moment the parameter is assigned with that value it accepts as a Unicode string. Hope I explained the point clearly.