# Select Query giving output as ??????????? with different language text

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Why is this query giving me ???????? as output.

```
 Declare     @Search    NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'اختبار كتاب اللغة العربية'
 SET @Search = N''+ @Search
 select   @Search
```

Where as  this one works fine :-

```
 Declare     @Search    NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'اختبار كتاب اللغة العربية'
 select   @Search
```

I want to make my query dynamic. Is there any other way I can do it?

Dynamic in the sence I can pass anything in the @Search parameter. I have a .NET application where I will pass the string to be searched in the @Search parameter which can be either English or Arabic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need to prefix a string literal with N to identify it as a Unicode string, otherwise it is treated at though it only contains single-byte characters.

Can you elaborate on "I want to make my query dynamic"?

```
Declare     @Search    NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'اختبار كتاب اللغة العربية'
```

When you execute this line it is treating the string literal as a single-byte literal and assigning it to the variable @Search. The variable is capable of storing a unicode string (but you didn't assign one to it). By the time you reference it later, the text has already been modified and you have already lost some of the encoding and it can't be recovered. You have to prefix the literal with N at the point you assign it to the variable.

Is there are reason why you can't put that prefix in your script?

Comment: That's what I am doing in the first case, if not then can you please tell me how to do it. Thanks

Comment: Edited to try to cover this in more detail.

Comment: Oh great man, your great words helped me in solving my problem. So instead of changing in the back end I prefixed the N from the front end itself. Thanks

Comment: Just through experience of working with multi-language applications to be honest, and needing to know how to work with unicode when adding translations for double-byte languages.

Comment: Oh it is great to share knowledge with experience people like you.